# How to change ranger current line face?

Tags: dired, customize

I can not figure out how to change current line bg in ranger - I'm unable to find customize group for that, is that possible at all? Maybe its inherited from other dired face, can somebody point me out to that face if its so? Thx.

Comment: I don't use `ranger.el`, but I see only two locations in the source that sets a face -- `ranger--header-new-tab` and `ranger--header-tabs`.  If those are indeed the source of the behavior you wish to change, then you can either modify the source-code directly and then `M-x byte-comple-file` if there was previously a `ranger.elc` next to `ranger.el` or `ranger.el.gz`.  Or, you can put `(require 'ranger)` in your `.emacs` file and underneath that put the same functions with the same names and  modify them -- e.g., remove `:inherit font-lock-builtin-face` and change background/foreground colors.

Comment: Put the cursor somewhere on the face you want to change, then do `C-u C-x =` and it will show you a bunch of information about the character under point, including the face and any overlays.  You can click on the different things to figure out which one to change.

Comment: If the face has been set with a hard-coded function such as `ranger--header-new-tab` or `ranger--header-tabs` it cannot be entirely changed with `M-x customize-face`.  For example, you could change the value of `font-lock-builtin-face` with `M-x customize-face`, but you could not change `:background "#787878"` or `:foreground "black"` in `ranger--header-new-tab` because it is hard-coded.  Likewise, you could not change `:background "#323232"` in `ranger--header-tabs` because it is hard-coded.  The hard-coding of faces in a function generally requires modification of the function itself.

Comment: Try M-x customize-face hl-line